# Finding height in Binary Search Tree

Tags: algorithm, recursion, binary-search-tree

I was wondering if anybody could help me rework this method to find the height of a binary search tree. So far, my code looks like this. However, the answer I'm getting is larger than the actual height by 1. But when I remove the +1 from my return statements, it's less than the actual height by 1. I'm still trying to wrap my head around recursion with these BST. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
public int findHeight(){
    if(this.isEmpty()){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        TreeNode<T> node = root;
        return findHeight(node);
    }
}
private int findHeight(TreeNode<T> aNode){
    int heightLeft = 0;
    int heightRight = 0;
    if(aNode.left!=null)
        heightLeft = findHeight(aNode.left);
    if(aNode.right!=null)
        heightRight = findHeight(aNode.right);
    if(heightLeft > heightRight){
        return heightLeft+1;
    }
    else{
        return heightRight+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I got it to return the correct height by returning findHeight(node)-1 in my public method. However I just feel like this is sloppy code, any suggestions on a revamp?

Comment: Is this the right approach for solving the tree height ?https://github.com/joeyajames/Python/issues/1

Answer (score 152, accepted):

The problem lies in your base case.

"The height of a tree is the length of the path from the root to the deepest node in the tree. A (rooted) tree with only a node (the root) has a height of zero." - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree)

If there is no node, you want to return -1 not 0.  This is because you are adding 1 at the end.

So if there isn't a node, you return -1 which cancels out the +1.

```
int findHeight(TreeNode<T> aNode) {
    if (aNode == null) {
        return -1;
    }

    int lefth = findHeight(aNode.left);
    int righth = findHeight(aNode.right);

    if (lefth > righth) {
        return lefth + 1;
    } else {
        return righth + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this works correctly without having to subtract 1 in my public method. I am still confused as to how this method works with recursion. I declared ints left and right after the if statement, but I dont understand how they are incremented through this method

Comment: This method works by subtracting 1 at the base case, they are incremented like every other method given, when you go deeper into the tree you add 1 to the height.

Comment: where did you find your quote `The height of a tree is the length of the path from the root to the deepest node in the tree. A (rooted) tree with only a node (the root) has a height of zero`? In the wiki page, there is no such quote

Comment: For those confused about how this recursion works, I've made a video which first explains the process on a high level, and then we run through the code with an example: [Find height of binary tree](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AWIJwNf0ZQE). Hopefully many of you will find it useful, and in that case we should probably add it to this answer.

Comment: "The height of a node in a tree is the number of edges on the longest simple downward path from the node to a leaf, and the height of a tree is the height of its root." is from p. 1177 of CLRS (3rd ed.). Based on this definition, a tree consisting of a single (root) node has height zero, which implies this is the only correct answer.

Comment: @cute_ptr - very helpful video to understand the recursive nature of this algorithm. Thanks!!

Comment: Is your code same as this??
```java
int findHeight(TreeNode<T> aNode) {
    if (aNode == null) {
        return -1;
    }
   else{
    int lefth = findHeight(aNode.left);
    int righth = findHeight(aNode.right);
    if (lefth > righth) {
        return lefth + 1;
    } else {
        return righth + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: why +1 .. for my height 2 tree it's showing height 3 because of +1 plz explain this...

Answer (score 41):

The height of a binary search tree is equal to `number of layers - 1`.

See the diagram at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree

Your recursion is good, so just subtract one at the root level.

Also note, you can clean up the function a bit by handling null nodes:

```
int findHeight(node) {
  if (node == null) return 0;
  return 1 + max(findHeight(node.left), findHeight(node.right));
}
```

Comment: My first attempt at this method I used something along these lines however I kept getting a StackOverFlow exception for some reason when I ran my code? Im assuming because I check for pointers pointing to null?

Comment: (Removed comment about c++, which doesn't apply).  It's likely that your "node == null" wasn't terminating properly.

Comment: Stephen, shouldn't it be 0 for a single-node tree?  This returns 1.

Comment: @Matthew: You're right, but I had suggested that his public function subtract one from the result.  Instead, you could "fix" the recursive function by returning -1 in the base case.

Comment: for a single node tree height is 0. so for an empty tree, the height is -1. this is why `return -1` works and not `return 0` when the node is NULL

Answer (score 28):

```
int getHeight(Node node) {
 if (node == null) return -1;

 return 1 + Math.max(getHeight(node.left), getHeight(node.right));
}
```

Answer (score 11):

In my opinion, your code would benefit from being simplified a bit. Rather than attempting to end the recursion when a ***child*** pointer is null, only end it when the ***current*** pointer is null. That makes the code a lot simpler to write. In pseudo-code, it looks something like this:

```
if (node = null)
    return 0;
else
    left = height(node->left);
    right = height(node->right);
    return 1 + max(left, right);
```

Comment: Can't call a method on a null object, though :)

Comment: @jemfinch, where is he calling it on a null object, isn't that what the base case is for?

Comment: @jemfinch:I guess it's a good thing I didn't suggest doing such a thing!

Comment: why do you return 0 instead of -1?

Comment: @JerryCoffin I am not doing any homework. Is it 0 or -1? And why?

Comment: @Faraz: That depends on what you consider to be the height of a single-node tree. Some consider that a height of 0 (in which case you return -1) and others consider it a height of 1 (in which case you return 0).

Answer (score 5):

```
class Solution{
    public static int getHeight(Node root) {
        int height = -1;

        if (root == null) {
            return height;
        } else {
            height = 1 + Math.max(getHeight(root.left), getHeight(root.right));
        }

        return height;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

For people like me who like one line solutions:

```
public int getHeight(Node root) {
    return Math.max(root.left != null ? getHeight(root.left) : -1, 
                    root.right != null ? getHeight(root.right) : -1) 
                    + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a concise and hopefully correct way to express it:

```
  private int findHeight(TreeNode<T> aNode){
    if(aNode == null || (aNode.left == null && aNode.right == null))
      return 0;
    return Math.max(findHeight(aNode.left), findHeight(aNode.right)) + 1;
  }
```

If the current node is null, there's no tree.  If both children are, there's a single layer, which means 0 height.  This uses the definition of height (mentioned by Stephen) as # of layers - 1

Answer (score 4):

This is untested, but fairly obviously correct:

```
private int findHeight(Treenode<T> aNode) {
  if (aNode.left == null && aNode.right == null) {
    return 0; // was 1; apparently a node with no children has a height of 0.
  } else if (aNode.left == null) {
    return 1 + findHeight(aNode.right);
  } else if (aNode.right == null) {
    return 1 + findHeight(aNode.left);
  } else {
    return 1 + max(findHeight(aNode.left), findHeight(aNode.right));
  }
}
```

Often simplifying your code is easier than figuring out why it's off by one.  This code is easy to understand: the four possible cases are clearly handled in an obviously correct manner:

- If both the left and right trees are null, return 0, since a single node by definition has a height of 0. (was 1)
- If either the left or right trees (but not both!) are null, return the height of the non-null tree, plus 1 to account for the added height of the current node.
- If neither tree is null, return the height of the taller subtree, again plus one for the current node.

Comment: This code works, and is clearer than what I had however, it is still  returning the height +1. In my book, height is defined as the length of the path from the root to its deepest leaf. So from my understanding a BST containing 15, 25, 30, 45 (in this order) would have a height of only 3 correct?

Comment: Actually, a tree with only the root node has a height of 0 not 1.

Comment: Strange.  It really ought not be called "height" if what they really mean is "paths-to-descend," but that seems to be the standard terminology, unfortunately.  The correct way to fix this is to change the first case (node.left == null && node.right == null) to return 0.

Answer (score 3):

```
    public void HeightRecursive()
    {
        Console.WriteLine( HeightHelper(root) ); 
    }

    private int HeightHelper(TreeNode node)
    {
        if (node == null)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1 + Math.Max(HeightHelper(node.LeftNode),HeightHelper(node.RightNode));           
        }
    }
```

C# code.
Include these two methods in your BST class. you need two method to calculate height of tree. HeightHelper calculate it, & HeightRecursive print it in main().

Answer (score 2):

The definition given above of the height is incorrect. That is the definition of the depth.

"The depth of a node *M* in a tree is the length of the path from the root of the tree to *M*. The height of a tree is one more than the depth of the deepest node in the tree. All nodes of depth *d* are at level *d* in the tree. The root is the only node at level 0, and its depth is 0."

**Citation**: "A Practical Introduction to Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis"
Edition 3.2 (Java Version)
Clifford A. Shaffer
Department of Computer Science
Virginia Tech
Blacksburg, VA 24061

Answer (score 2):

```
public int height(){

    if(this.root== null) return 0;

    int leftDepth = nodeDepth(this.root.left, 1);
    int rightDepth = nodeDepth(this.root.right, 1);

    int height = leftDepth > rightDepth? leftDepth: rightDepth;

    return height;
}


private int nodeDepth(Node node, int startValue){

    int nodeDepth = 0;

    if(node.left == null && node.right == null) return startValue;
    else{
        startValue++;
        if(node.left!= null){
            nodeDepth = nodeDepth(node.left, startValue);
        }

        if(node.right!= null){
            nodeDepth = nodeDepth(node.right, startValue);
        }
    }

    return nodeDepth;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

//function to find height of BST

```
int height(Node* root) {
    if(root == NULL){
        return -1;
    }

    int sum=0;
    int rheight = height(root->right);
    int lheight = height(root->left);

    if(lheight>rheight){
        sum = lheight +1;
    }
    if(rheight > lheight){
        sum = rheight + 1;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int height(Node* root) {
        if(root==NULL) return -1;
        return max(height(root->left),height(root->right))+1;
}
```

Take of maximum height from left and right subtree and add 1 to it.This also handles the base case(height of Tree with 1 node is 0).

Answer (score 2):

I know that I’m late to the party. After looking into wonderful answers provided here, I thought mine will add some value to this post. Although the posted answers are amazing and easy to understand however, all are calculating the height to the BST in linear time. I think this can be improved and Height can be retrieved in **constant** time, hence writing this answer – hope you will like it.
Let’s start with the **Node** class:

```
public class Node
{
    public Node(string key)
    {
        Key = key;
        Height = 1;
    }    

    public int Height { get; set; } 
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public Node Left { get; set; }
    public Node Right { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Key}";
    }
}
```

**BinarySearchTree** class

So you might have guessed the trick here… Im keeping node instance variable Height to keep track of each node when added.
Lets move to the BinarySearchTree class that allows us to add nodes into our BST:

```
public class BinarySearchTree
{
    public Node RootNode { get; private set; }

    public void Put(string key)
    {
        if (ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return;
        }

        RootNode = Put(RootNode, key);
    }

    private Node Put(Node node, string key)
    {
        if (node == null) return new Node(key);

        if (node.Key.CompareTo(key) < 0)
        {
            node.Right = Put(node.Right, key);
        }
        else
        {
            node.Left = Put(node.Left, key);
        }       
        
        // since each node has height property that is maintained through this Put method that creates the binary search tree.
        // calculate the height of this node by getting the max height of its left or right subtree and adding 1 to it.        
        node.Height = Math.Max(GetHeight(node.Left), GetHeight(node.Right)) + 1;
        return node;
    }

    private int GetHeight(Node node)
    {
        return node?.Height ?? 0;
    }

    public Node Get(Node node, string key)
    {
        if (node == null) return null;
        if (node.Key == key) return node;

        if (node.Key.CompareTo(key) < 0)
        {
            // node.Key = M, key = P which results in -1
            return Get(node.Right, key);
        }

        return Get(node.Left, key);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(string key)
    {
        Node node = Get(RootNode, key);
        return node != null;
    }
}
```

Once we have added the key, values in the BST, we can just call Height property on the RootNode object that will return us the Height of the RootNode tree in **constant** time.
The trick is to keep the height updated when a new node is added into the tree.
Hope this helps someone out there in the wild world of computer science enthusiast!

**Unit test:**

```
[TestCase("SEARCHEXAMPLE", 6)]
[TestCase("SEBAQRCHGEXAMPLE", 6)]
[TestCase("STUVWXYZEBAQRCHGEXAMPLE", 8)]
public void HeightTest(string data, int expectedHeight)
{
    // Arrange.
    var runner = GetRootNode(data);

    
    //  Assert.
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedHeight, runner.RootNode.Height);
}

private BinarySearchTree GetRootNode(string data)
{
    var runner = new BinarySearchTree();
    foreach (char nextKey in data)
    {
        runner.Put(nextKey.ToString());
    }

    return runner;
}
```

**Note**: This idea of keeping the Height of tree maintained in every Put operation is inspired by the Size of BST method found in the 3rd chapter (page 399) of [Algorithm (Fourth Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032157351X) book.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this question could mean two different things...

1. Height is the **number of nodes in the longest branch**:-

   `int calcHeight(node* root){
   if(root==NULL)
       return 0;
   int l=calcHeight(root->left);
   int r=calcHeight(root->right);
   if(l>r)
       return l+1;
   else
       return r+1;
   }`
2. Height is the **total number of nodes in the tree** itself:

   `int calcSize(node* root){
       if(root==NULL)
       return 0;
   return(calcSize(root->left)+1+calcSize(root->right));
   }`

Answer (score 1):

```
public int getHeight(Node node)
{
    if(node == null)
        return 0;

    int left_val = getHeight(node.left);
    int right_val = getHeight(node.right);
    if(left_val > right_val)
        return left_val+1;
    else
        return right_val+1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in C#

```
    private static int heightOfTree(Node root)
    {
        if (root == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        int left = 1 + heightOfTree(root.left);
        int right = 1 + heightOfTree(root.right);

        return Math.Max(left, right);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set a tempHeight as a static variable(initially 0).

static void findHeight(Node node, int count) {

```
    if (node == null) {
        return;
    }
    if ((node.right == null) && (node.left == null)) {
        if (tempHeight < count) {
            tempHeight = count;

        }

    }

    findHeight(node.left, ++count);
    count--; //reduce the height while traversing to a different branch
    findHeight(node.right, ++count);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in Java a bit lengthy but works..

```
public static int getHeight (Node root){
    int lheight = 0, rheight = 0;
    if(root==null) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        if(root.left != null) {
            lheight = 1 + getHeight(root.left);
            System.out.println("lheight" + " " + lheight);
        }
        if (root.right != null) {
            rheight = 1+ getHeight(root.right);
            System.out.println("rheight" + " " + rheight);
        }
        if(root != null && root.left == null && root.right == null) {
            lheight += 1; 
            rheight += 1;
        }

    }
    return Math.max(lheight, rheight);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 int getHeight(Node* root)
 {
   if(root == NULL) return -1;
   else             return max(getHeight(root->left), getHeight(root->right)) + 1;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Height of Binary Tree**

```
public static int height(Node root)
    {
        // Base case: empty tree has height 0
        if (root == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        // recursively for left and right subtree and consider maximum depth
        return 1 + Math.max(height(root.left), height(root.right));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that reads this!!!!

HEIGHT is defined as the number of nodes in the longest path from the root node to a leaf node. Therefore: a tree with only a root node has a height of 1 and not 0.

The LEVEL of a given node is the distance from the root plus 1. Therefore: The root is on level 1, its child nodes are on level 2 and so on.

(Information courtesy of Data Structures: Abstraction and Design Using Java, 2nd Edition, by Elliot B. Koffman & Paul A. T. Wolfgang) - Book used in Data Structures Course I am currently taking at Columbus State University.

Comment: FOR ANYONE ELSE THAT READS THIS!!!! This definition of height is wrong! The height of a tree is the number of **edges** from the root node to  the furthest leaf node (or one of the furthest if there are a number of equidistant leaves). Since it's edges, a tree with only a root node will have a height of zero. Go to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Definition and read "Height of node" and "Height of tree". Additionally both the Cormen and the Weiss algorithms textbooks backup this definition. The given definition of level is correct.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dGcV.png)

According to "Introduction to Algorithms" by Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest, and Clifford Stein, following is the definition of tree height:

> The height of a node in a
>   tree is the number of edges on the longest simple downward path from the node to
>   a leaf, and the height of a tree is the height of its root. The height of a tree is also
>   equal to the largest depth of any node in the tree.

Following is my ruby solution. Most of the people forgot about height of empty tree or tree of single node in their implementation.

```
def height(node, current_height)
  return current_height if node.nil? || (node.left.nil? && node.right.nil?)
  return [height(node.left, current_height + 1), height(node.right, current_height + 1)].max if node.left && node.right
  return height(node.left, current_height + 1) if node.left
  return height(node.right, current_height + 1)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int maxDepth(BinaryTreeNode root) {
    if(root == null || (root.left == null && root.right == null)) {
       return 0;
    }

    return 1 + Math.max(maxDepth(root.left), maxDepth(root.right));
}
```

Comment: Hi Phat, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you add some sentences to your answer to explain what the central point is. That would make it more helpful.

Comment: btw you don't need to check on null root.left and root.right

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this myself trying to find something elegant that still resulted in the correct value. Here's what I came up with using Swift. Note that `height` is a computed variable and technically not a function.

```
class Node<T: Comparable>: NSObject
{
    var left: Node<T>? = nil
    var right: Node<T>? = nil
 
    var isLeaf: Bool { left == nil && right == nil }

    var height: Int {
        if isLeaf { return 0 }
        return 1 + max(left?.height ?? 0, right?.height ?? 0)
    }
}
```

There's more to this Node definition but you can see the `left` and `right` variables (possibly nil) and an `isLeaf` var that is `true` when both `left` and `right` are `nil`. Might not be the most efficient but I believe it yields the correct result.

The BST definition also has a computed `height` variable and returns -1 when the tree is empty.

```
class BST<T: Comparable>: NSObject
{
    var root: Node<T>?
    var height: Int { root != nil ? root!.height : -1 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HackerRank Day 22: Finding height in Binary Search Tree, in C#.

     static int getHeight(Node root)
        {
            //Write your code here
            int countr = 0,countl=0;
            Node Leftsubtree=root.left;
            Node rightsubtree = root.right;
            int data=root.data;
             if(root==null ||(root.left == null && root.right == null))
            {
                return 0;
            }
             else
            {
                while (Leftsubtree != null)
                {
                        if(Leftsubtree.data<data)
                        {
                        Leftsubtree = Leftsubtree.left==null?Leftsubtree.right:Leftsubtree.left;
                        countl++;
                        }
                }
                while (rightsubtree != null)
                {
                    if (rightsubtree.data > data)
                    {
                        rightsubtree = rightsubtree.right == null ? rightsubtree.left : rightsubtree.right;
                        countr++;
                    }
    
                }
            }
    
            return countr >= countl ? countr : countl;
    
    
        }
```