# Calculating Height of Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I've been searching for how to calculate the height of a Binary Search Tree and my research has lead me to the following implementation. I'm still trying to wrap my head around why it should work, but I'm also unsure why it isn't working. Here is my height function.

```
int BinaryTreeNode::height() const {
    int lefth = left->height();
    int righth = right->height();
    if(lefth > righth) {
        return lefth + 1;
    } else {
        return righth + 1;
    }
}
```

and here's my class definition for the node

```
class BinaryTreeNode {
  public:
    Data * nodeData;
    BinaryTreeNode * left;
    BinaryTreeNode * right;
```

When I try to run it my program locksup and crashes. Am I missing something obvious?

EDIT: Why shouldn't this work?

```
int BinaryTreeNode::height() const {
    int l = 0;
    if (left != NULL) {
        left->height();
    }
    int r = 0;
    if (right != NULL) {
        right->height();
    }
    if (l > r) {
        return l + 1;
    }
    else {
        return r + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use a debugger ?

Comment: You're missing the base cases. Without base cases, you'll hit an infinite recursion.

Comment: The first thing you do is call `height()` again, you have an infinite loop/

Comment: What do you mean that it "isn't working"? What happens when you compile and run your code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding height in Binary Search Tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597637/finding-height-in-binary-search-tree)

Comment: "Why shouldn't this work?" -- Because it's obviously wrong. It seems that you're just copying and pasting code without any idea of what it does or how to figure out what it does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your tree is not infinite. So, I suppose some nodes do not have left or right childs, and the pointers `left` and/or `right` are null in this case. You have to check for their existence before trying to use them.

Try that function instead:

```
int BinaryTreeNode::height()
{
    int l = left ? left->height() : 0;  // height of left child, if any
    int r = right ? right->height() : 0; // idem for right child
    return 1 + max(l, r);
}
```

Note: I have simplified your computations of height.

Comment: Your code works but I tried rewriting it like but it doesn't. What did I break? (put the code in OP)

Comment: @SeanLafferty: What you pasted is the original version of *my* code, which indeed was broken (I forgot the assignment). Now it works. But I admit this version by Synxis is better

Comment: @SeanLafferty: Btw, the OP is *you* (Original Poster), not the question.

Comment: The function returns a height of 1 with my updated code, but yours correctly outputs 4 (which is the height). I thought our code would do the same thing but maybe max() does something I didn't account for in my rudimentary version?

Comment: @SeanLafferty: Again, that is because the version you posted lacks the assignments.

Comment: @SeanLafferty: Should be `l = left->height();` instead of just `left->height();`, same for `right`. That was a mistake of mine, sorry for that

Comment: @Sean I agree with Andy, the version you posted is his original one, which was missing the assignment. Try mine, or his new one, for example.

Comment: Thanks I have it working now. I'm still a little shaky on how it works though, like aren't r and l both 0 before it gets to the max operation where it adds the 1 to either or?

Comment: The ternary operator recursively calls `height()` if the child exists, and assign the result to the variable, or assign 0 to it (height of non-existent child is 0). So, `l` and `r` are the heights of repectively the left and right child. Then the height of the node is 1 + the maximum height between left and right. See [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4213hs1(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: @SeanLafferty If you have absolutely no idea how to read C code, just say so.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your function never checks if the child pointers are `NULL`, so apart from dereferencing an invalid pointer, you have a recursive function that misses a base case:

Try this version:

```
int BinaryTreeNode::height() const 
{
    int lefth = 0;
    if (left != NULL) { lefth = left->height(); }

    int righth = 0;
    if (righth != NULL) { righth = right->height(); }

    if (lefth > righth) { return lefth + 1; } 
    else { return righth + 1; }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to assign the value of `left->height()` to `lefth` (and same for right child) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Even I was facing the same problem, well the problem with your code is that in your function you are using recurssion twice and you are going to the left and right extremities, but you arent checking the possibility if the right child of one of the parent node in left subtree has its own children, hence your are not traversing to the last leaf node in your tree! hope this helps