# Depth of a Node in a Binary Tree (Java)

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

The depth of a node is the number of edges from root to that node, right? But how to find it by a method like findDepth(Node node) in java?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding height in Binary Search Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597637/finding-height-in-binary-search-tree)

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple exercise on recursion. Implement it recursively.

`findDepth(Node node)`

In the code of the `findDepth` function/method do this:
1) if the node has a parent return `1 + findDepth(parent)`
2) if the node has no parent (i.e. is the root) return `0`

Answer (score 0):

So, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597637/finding-height-in-binary-search-tree) answer, already on stackOverflow, you can do this:

```
int findDepth(Node node) {
    if (aNode == null) {
         return -1;
    }

    int lefth = findHeight(node.left);
    int righth = findHeight(node.right);

    if (lefth > righth) {
        return lefth + 1;
    } else {
        return righth + 1;
    }
}
```